Antlr4 PLSQLParser in Python giving mismatched input '<EOF>' with all SQL
I am using Antlr4 Python for PLSQL.
The grammar is from here:
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql/plsql
Here is the input - a very simple SQL script:
SELECT col1, col2
FROM tab1
ORDER BY col1;

The `od -c -h output for this script is:
od -c -h
0000000   S   E   L   E   C   T       c   o   l   1   ,       c   o   l
           4553    454c    5443    6320    6c6f    2c31    6320    6c6f
0000020   2  \n   F   R   O   M       t   a   b   1  \n   O   R   D   E
           0a32    5246    4d4f    7420    6261    0a31    524f    4544
0000040   R       B   Y       c   o   l   1   ;  \n
           2052    5942    6320    6c6f    3b31    000a
0000053

Here is my Python script to print out the tokens:
from antlr4 import *
from antlr4.tree.Tree import TerminalNodeImpl
#from antlr4.tree.Tree import ParseTree
from antlr4.tree.Trees import Trees
from PlSqlLexer import PlSqlLexer
from PlSqlParser import PlSqlParser
from PlSqlParserListener import PlSqlParserListener


def handleTree(tree, lvl=0):
    for child in tree.getChildren():
        if isinstance(child, TerminalNode):
            print(lvl*'│ ' + '└─', child)
        else:
            handleTree(child, lvl+1)


class KeyPrinter(PlSqlParserListener):
    def enterSelect_statement(self, ctx):
        handleTree(ctx, 0)

def main():

        with open( "myscript.sql" ) as file:

            filesrc = file.read()

            lexer = PlSqlLexer(InputStream(filesrc))
            tokens = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
            tokens.fill()
            parser = PlSqlParser(CommonTokenStream(lexer))
            tree = parser.sql_script()

            printer = KeyPrinter()
            walker = ParseTreeWalker()
            walker.walk(printer, tree)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


The output I get is:
line 4:0 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'ABORT', 'ABS', 'ABOUT' ...........
.
.
...... 'EXTEND', 'MAXLEN', 'PERSISTABLE', 'POLYMORPHIC', 'STRUCT', 'TDO', 'WM_CONCAT', '.', DELIMITED_ID, '(', '_', PROMPT_MESSAGE, START_CMD, REGULAR_ID}


I thought maybe the isue is the grammar is for PLSQL rather than simple SQL, so I tried with a simple PLSQL script as follows:
DECLARE
   l_tmp  NUMBER ;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(1)
   INTO l_tmp
   FROM   mytab;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' Count: ' || l_tmp );

END;
/

But I still the same error:
line 13:0 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'ABORT', 'ABS', ...............
How to fix ?

Instead of lexer = PlSqlLexer(InputStream(filesrc)), try lexer = PlSqlLexer(InputStream(FileStream("myscript.sql","utf-8"))?

Thank you. It didn't solve the issue unfortunately. But I found removing the tokens.fill() resolved the issue.

I see the problem. You have two calls to CommonTokenStream(lexer), first with tokens = CommonTokenStream(lexer), then again with parser = PlSqlParser(CommonTokenStream(lexer)). tokens.fill() is fine, but don't sandwich it between two calls to CommonTokenStream(), of which only one call is needed.

@kaby76 Add this as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you.

Removing the token.fill() line solved the issue.
